# Run newman using date range?

Tags: postman

Is there is a way to choose a date range from the csv example from line 10 to 30?

We are using the below command to run our collection but it's run all the CSV files.

Example:
`newman run mycollection.jason -e dev_environment.json -g glb_enviroment.json -d data.csv -k`

using the

`-n, --iteration-count [number]`

we were only able to set how many rows from the CSV ran from the beginning.

Comment: Edited for grammar and clarity

Comment: Hello, currently it's unclear what you're asking.  Here is [a guide on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will increase your chance to get an appropriate answer. It also helps you solving the question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking to do is not possible with newman. You would need to manipulate the CSV file in some sort of wrapper script first before invoking newman.